# TypeError xxx is not a function

Tags: javascript

All, I am struggling with an error which says `TypeError: curTemplete.addSection is not a function`, Please forgive that I am not familiar with the js OO, Please help to review my problem. thanks.

The code looks like below.

**Templete.js**

```
LayoutTemplete=function(currentTmpContainer,templeteId,data)
{
    var curTemplete = this;

    curTemplete.addSection(null, null);//this line run with error above.


    this.addSection = function(uiItem, data) {
        alert('ddd');
    };
};
```

In the **dom ready event**.

```
function loadTempleteContent(templeteId)
{
    var jData=[{name: 'jerry'},{name: 'mike'},{name: 'claire'}];
    var tmp = new LayoutTemplete($("#currentTmpContainer"),templeteId,jData);
}
```

Comment: Got a JSFiddle? Also, what does your code do? It would be helpful if we knew

Comment: What utility are you using for templates? It is most probable that the function isn't defined because you haven't loaded the templating utility (yet). But first, are you using an AMD loader?  Because that would also affect WHEN the utility loads.

Comment: At the moment you call `curTemplete.addSection`, the property hasn't been defined yet. You do that only after the `if` statement. If you move the `if` statement after you assign the property it should be alright.

Comment: put `this.addSection` before `var curTemplete = this;`

Comment: Re your edit: Even without the `if` statement, the problem is still the same. You cannot call the function before it was created. Call it after you assigned it.

Comment: I am sorry for the code `if (true)`,I had remove it . I just demo what the code looks like. I had updated it .thanks.

Comment: Hi ,all , This code is pure js , not using any templete js lib. just use the jquery .I am sure about that . thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot call a function before it was defined. This has nothing to do with OOP. Consider this example:

```
foo();
var foo = function() {
    alert(42);
};
```

It will throw a similar error.

Define the function/the property **before** you access it:

```
this.addSection = function(uiItem, data) {
    alert('ddd');
};

this.addSection(null, null);
```

Better yet, define `addSection` on the prototype, so that you don't create a new  function every time you create an instances of `LayoutTemplete`.

```
LayoutTemplete = function(currentTmpContainer,templeteId,data) {
    this.addSection(null, null);
};

LayoutTemplete.prototype.addSection = function(uiItem, data) {
    alert('ddd');
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Felix is trying to tell you what your issue is, here it is explicitly:

```
var curTemplete = this;

curTemplete.addSection(null, null);//this line run with error above.
```

Here you reference and attempt to call `curTemplete.addection`, which has not been assigned a value yet, so it resolves to `undefined`. When the call is attempted, undefined is not a function (as the error tells you). `addSection` is not defined until the assignment below:

```
this.addSection = function(uiItem, data) {
    alert('ddd');
};
```

Now it's defined. Move the assignment before the call (and if you're going to assign `this` to a local variable, you may as well use it):

```
var curTemplete = this;
curTemplete.addSection = function(uiItem, data) {
    alert('ddd');
};
curTemplete.addSection(null, null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindly answer and comments , It is nice .